# Photoshop CC 2019: How do I open an image in Photoshop without being forced to create a new document?

Tags: images, adobe-photoshop

All I want to do is open an image in Photoshop CC 2019 
[image: image opened in photoshop]

I've been able to do with all of my photos till today. When I attempt to open any image that I've recently downloaded, I'm taken to the "New Document" Dialogue Box
[image: "New Document" Dialogue Box]

**How do I open an image in photoshop without being forced to create a new document?**

Comment: What is it about creating a new document that is objectionable?

Comment: I'm not given the option to choose the original image size and the background contents option forces a white, black or transparent background with no image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Download any JPG and try to open it.  It seemed to be a file specific issue.
- If that does not work

  1. Open Creative Cloud Desktop
  2. Go to photoshop and click update
  3. uncheck "import previous settings and preferences"
     [image]
  4. Close your photoshop then click on continue.